# Built-in way to pipe data from DevOps to Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-explorer

I'd like to take all my build (pipeline run) data from Azure DevOps and compose queries on it in Azure Data Explorer, to get more advanced sums and charts than you can get in the basic analytics available inside Azure DevOps.

Is there a *built-in* way I can "connect" these two services? Or do I need to write some batch script that scrapes the Azure DevOps REST API and dumps the data into a Data Explorer database in a predefined format?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the azure devops, we can use the [Azure Data Explorer tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX) to help us connect the pipeline to Azure Data Explorer.
But we can't help to connect all builds data to Azure Data Explorer, so we need to use the api: [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to help us get all data and then put the info to the Data Explorer database.
Also, here is a refer doc: [Azure DevOps Task for Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/devops#create-folders) might help you.

Comment: Thanks Yujun - I've accepted this answer, but I think the end result is, you need to write your own custom logic to scrape the REST API and then ingest the data into ADX. The first part is easy, the second part is not -- the Kusto "ingestion" API is very confusing and clunky to use, in my opinion. But I am working on it!